# setting background image behind bootstrap container to be full width and stretching it on window resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background

JS FIDDLE to replicate what I am having trouble with and the code from the fiddle below: https://jsfiddle.net/ey0n651q/

```
<div class="first-section">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-7 order-2 order-sm-2 order-md-1">
    <div class="left-side">
      <div class="header">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      </div>
      <p>
        <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
      </p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="block">
            <div class="img-block">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff">
            </div>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="block">
            <div class="img-block">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff">
            </div>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="block">
            <div class="img-block">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff">
            </div>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="block">
            <div class="img-block">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff">
            </div>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button class="btn-primary">MORE DETAILS</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-5 order-1 order-sm-1 order-md-2">
    <div class="right-side">
  <!--MOBILE CODE IS HERE IN DESKTOP THIS IS EMPTY BLOCK-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.first-section {
background-image: url('https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png');
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
 }

.block {
text-align: center;
}

.img-block {
 height: 50px;
}

.button {
 text-align: center;
 }

 .right-side {
   /*mobile code goes here-not relevant to this*/
 }
```

Okay, this is a little complicated. I have a page where I need the background image to be outside of the bootstrap container to fit the full screen. When I resize the browser, I need the BG image to stretch out if the screen is bigger. At the moment it stays attached to the right of the screen and just pulls away leaving a big white space. The row has 2 columns, left side made up of 7 columns and right side made up of 5. The right side is empty. Idealy, I would want the background image attached to the right side but then it won't stretch past the container and it will leave a white space after the background image. I have attached the screenshots below to explain everything that is happening. The first section is where I have put the BG image. It is outside of the container for bootstrap and the rows and all content. That was the only way I could get the BG image to stretch to the right past the padding and margins bootstrap adds in its container. Any help will be great. I know there is some JS I can write but just looking for suggestions and ideas. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `background-size:cover` ?? Hey, there is no code here. Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette This is more of an idea and brainstorm type of question. But I can post an example code if you like.

Comment: A CodePen or a live link will do. Now "brainstorm" questions may be "too broad" here on SO. Need a specific issue. The relevant code where the issue approximately is should be posted.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Here is a JSFiddle of my problem. Once you stretch the screen beyond 1400px width you see the left side doing what it is suppose to but the right side I need the BG image to start stretching out so it doesn't leave that white space in between. https://jsfiddle.net/ey0n651q/

Comment: So like this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/ey0n651q/1/)?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette not quite.. I need the image to stay within the right side only. (the column which occupies the right 5 columns.) but I can't put the BG image on that div because it needs to be outside of the container since container adds padding on the side.